# Delay loading Blob data immediately after inserting it

Tags: java, pdf, spring-data-jpa, blob

We are rewriting an old application in to SpringBoot using Spring Data JPA. In one flow, pdf file needs to be uploaded and then later displayed on the screen.

**Use case -**

1. Upload a pdf file in legacy application.
2. It gets stored in a db table as a Blob value.
3. From new application, I use below components to read it from db.

**Problem facing -**

1. User uploads a pdf from old application.
2. Immediately after pdf is uploaded, screen is refreshed in old app. User can see uploaded pdf.
3. Now, immediately if you go to new app & try displaying in new app, User can not view uploaded pdf.
4. If user waits for 30 seconds and try again, it works fine and user can see uploaded pdf.

**Debugging -**

1. For first 30 seconds, I always receive a "null" byte[].
2. After 30 seconds or so, I start receiving content in byte[].

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "DbTable")
public class DbEntity {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "db_id")
  private Integer id;

  @Blob
  @Column(name = "blob_column1")
  private byte[] blobColumn1;
}
```

```
@Repository
public interface DbEntityRepository extends CrudRepository<DbEntity, Integer> {

  @Query("from DbEntity e where e.id = :id")
  DbEntity getRecords(@Param("id") String id);
}
```

```
@Service
public class Service {
  
  @Autowired
  private DbEntityRepository repo;

  public byte[] getBlob(String id) {
    DbEntity record = repo.getRecords(id);
    return record.getBlobColumn1();
  }
}
```

**Update -**

- I have tried below scenarios to make sure issue is with new app only.

  1. Viewed pdf in old app right after it was uploaded (4-5 seconds delay). It opened fine.
  2. Viewed pdf in old app right after it was uploaded (4-5 seconds delay) from a different user's session. It opened fine. This rules out any kind of caching issues.
- Old application uses JDBC to perform db operations.

Comment: please check if this answers your question https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-save-saveandflush

Comment: Thanks for response. However, my issue is delay in reading the response from new app. I will edit my question to make it clear.